# Como inserir uma variável String em um hql?

Tags: java, hql

Preciso fazer uma consulta no banco e retornar apenas os valores baseados na variavel, meu código retorna a lista com todos os dados do campo cidade, desejo retornar apenas as cidades baseado no estado que o usuário selecionar antes. O retorno do estado (a variável que tem de ser inserida no hlq) seria 'sgEstado'

```
public List<FilialComplementoTO> findCidadesByDsCidade() throws IntegrationException {
        List cidades;
          List<FilialComplementoTO> listOk ;
        try {
              Session session = InitSessionFactory.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
                StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
                hql.append(" select g.dsCidade from FilialComplementoTO g ");
                hql.append(" group by g.dsCidade ");
                Query objQuery = session.createQuery(hql.toString());

                cidades = (List) objQuery.list();
                 listOk = new ArrayList<FilialComplementoTO>();
                for(Object obj: cidades){
                    FilialComplementoTO comple = new FilialComplementoTO();
                    comple.setDsCidade(obj.toString());
                    listOk.add(comple);
                }
                System.out.println(cidades);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).error(e.getMessage());
            throw new IntegrationException(e);
        }
        return listOk;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use parâmetros. Exemplo

```
StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();
hql.append(" select g.dsCidade from FilialComplementoTO g ");

// filtro utilizando parâmetro:
hql.append(" where g.sgEstado = :estado");
hql.append(" group by g.dsCidade ");
Query objQuery = session.createQuery(hql.toString());

// setando o valor do parâmetro:
objQuery.setParameter("estado", sgEstado)
```

Se o seu ORM (Hibernate, Eclipse, OpenJPA, ...) não suportar parâmetro nomeado, talvez você tenha que fazer assim:

```
...
hql.append(" where g.sgEstado = ?");
...
objQuery.setParameter(0, variavelStringContendoEstado)
```

Me lembro ainda de uma versão (que não me lembro qual) de um ORM (que não me lembro qual) onde os parâmetros eram indexados em 1. Neste caso, para o setar o primeiro parâmetro da query:

```
objQuery.setParameter(1, variavelStringContendoEstado)
```

Para mais detalhes, veja: [Oracle Documenation - Java Persistence API - Chapter 10. JPA Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13189_01/kodo/docs40/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html)

Comment: O próprio jdbc usa o índice começando por 1. +1 na resposta.